# Access Elements of Array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to access some elements of an array in matlab. Consider the scenario below :

```
a = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]

b = [1 2;2 1]
```

I want to access elements with indices (1,2) and (2,1) from a. I tried using a(b) etc. But none of the methods I tried worked.

How can this be done in matlab without using loops?

Also it would be helpful if you could suggest some good books for such basics in matlab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select a submatrix (not in any particular pattern) in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13091193/1336150).

Answer (score 1):

First, convert your subscripts to indices using [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
dim1sub = b(:,1);
dim2sub = b(:,2);

ind = sub2ind(size(a), dim1sub, dim2sub)
```

After you have the indices

```
a(ind)
```

will give you:

```
ans =

     2
     4
```

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) for more information on matrix indexing.

Comment: @EitanT of course, but I don't usually prefer one-liners when answering questions. They make it seem more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab lets you access a matrix with a linear index that scans through all the columns of the matrix. So in your case (with a 3x3) `a(2,1)=a(2)` and `a(1,2)=a(4)`. The answer that @HebeleHododo provided takes your row and column index and converts them into a linear index into matrix `a`. Just remember that if you want to index a different size matrix, you will need a different linear index for it.

Also, there is a lot of information available online to help with learning matlab at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/index.html#language-fundamentals or you can type `doc help` into the command window