# Matlab `image(image)=-1`?

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, filter, mask

I'm really new at matlab and I'm trying to understand this piece of code:

```
mask = false(size(image_map));
image_map(mask) = -1;
```

I understand that the first line is to create an array of logical zeros that is the same size as image_map, but what is this `image_map(mask)` for?

Sorry if it's a dumb question and the answers will be appreciated.

Comment: since mask is an array of logical zeros, the next line is yields an empty matrix because the index must be a positive integer or logical in the sense of Shai's answer

Comment: Related question: [How to select a submatrix (not in any particular pattern) in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091193).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In matlab you may access entries of a matrix is several ways. One is by linear indexing:

```
image_map( 4 ) % access the fourth element of image_map
```

However, there is a more efficient way, using [**logical indexing**](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html).
In this approach you create a logical matrix, **the same size** as `image_map` and then you can access all the extrines in `image_map` for which the locial matrix has the value `true`.