# Vector as column index in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

Given a matrix `A` (`mxn`) and a vector `B` (`mx1`) I want to create a vector `C` (`mx1`) in which each row element is the row element of `A` from a column indexed by `B`.
Is it possible to do this, without using loops?

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6];
B = [2 1 1].';
```

Then I want:

```
C = [2 3 5].';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the column subscripts of `B` to linear indices and then use them to reference elements in `A`:

```
idx = sub2ind(size(A), (1:size(A, 1)).', B);
C = A(idx);
```

(for more information, read the part about linear indexing in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091193#13093242)).