# How to store multiple indices into a new array

Tags: matlab, indexing, indices

I have a column of numbers, and I want to find those that are greater than 10 and then record their indices. I can do that for a single index with:

```
[y, I] = A(A>10)
```

where y stores the values, I stores the index, and A is the matrix name.

but MATLAB won't let me do it for more than one index. When I tried, it gave me the error:

"Indexing cannot yield multiple results. "

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I am very new to MATLAB and haven't figured out all the tricks yet.

Comment: related question: [How to select a submatrix (not in any particular pattern) in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091193/1336150#13093242) (see the part about logical indexing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking matlab to return multiple results, while A(A>10) would return only a column matrix. This would be one right way to do it:

```
I = A > 10;
y = A(I);
```

Or if you want them in a single line, you can do this:

```
[y, I] = deal(A(A>10), A>10);
```

Comment: Thank you that did it. We haven't gone over the deal function yet.

Comment: There's really no point in making a one-liner here. Readability is more important!

Comment: I had another quick question regarding this: instead of the elements in A>10, how would I format this to index the three greatest values?

Comment: For that you need to use [sort()](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)

Comment: Hint: if A is a 2D matrix, use the command A(:) to read it columnwise as a 1D matrix before using sort(). Also refer to the question which @EitanT has suggested to learn more about indexing.